# Can there be a function, that with the slope $f'(x_0) = 0$ at the single root $x_0$

Tags: derivatives

Let $f$ be a function of the form
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i x^i = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x+ a_0
$$
with $a_n, a_{n - 1}, ..., a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x_o$ be a single root of $f$
$$f(x_0) = 0 \iff f(x) = (x - x_0) * p(x)$$

Is ist true that there is no (polynomial) function with the slope of zero at $P(x_0/f(x_o))$?
$$
f'(x_0) = 0
$$

My approaches so far:

**Proof for any function of the form $f(x) = ax + b$, with $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus 0, b \in \mathbb{R}$**
$$
f'(x) = a \iff a \neq 0
$$

**Proof for any function of the form $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, with $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus 0,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$**
$$
x_{1/2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
$$
$$
f'(x) = 2ax + b
$$
$$
f'(x_{1/2}) = 2a\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} + b = \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}
$$
if $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} = 0$, then ther is no a double, not a single zero

**Proof for any function of the form $f(x) = (x - x_1)(x - x_2)(x - x_3)$**

$$
f'(x) = ((x -x_1) + (x - x_2)) * (x - x_3) + (x - x_1)(x - x_2)
$$

$f'(x_1) = (x -x_2) * (x - x_3)$, $f'(x_2) = (x-x_1) * (x - x_3)$, $f'(x_3) =(x - x_1)(x - x_2) $

All three are zero under the premise $x_1 \neq x_2 \neq x_3$ (single root)

*I am looking for a way of showing this for any polynomial function!*

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ factors as $f(x) = (x - x_0) p(x)$ with $p(x_0) \ne 0$, notice that

$$f'(x) = (x - x_0) p'(x) + p(x)$$

so that the derivative of $f'$ at $x_0$ is $p(x_0)$.

Comment: And how can you show, that $p(x_0) \neq 0$ (It must be of course, otherwise $x_0$ wouldn't be a single zero)

Comment: @Entimon If $p(x_0) = 0$, then $p$ factors as $(x - x_0) q(x)$, which leads to $f(x) = (x - x_0)^2 q(x)$. As a generalization, you can show that you have a root of multiplicity $n$ when the first $n$ derivatives are zero.

Comment: For what multiplicities of a root does this apply to (only single roots, or odd roots ...)?

Comment: @Entimon Any of them.

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^2$ with $x_0 = 0$ and $f'(x_0) = 0$?

Comment: @Entimon: What about it?  That's a double zero.

Comment: Yes, that factors as $(x - 0)^2$....

Comment: Yeah, so $f'(x_0) \neq 0$, if it's an single zero? Or does this apply also to e.g. a triple zero?

Comment: "Not a single zero" includes triple zeros.

Comment: So there is no $f(x) = (x - x_0)^3 * p(x)$ with $f'(x) \neq 0$???

Comment: No, there is not (and the answer shows why).